# python thread.join() not join to caller thread but to another assigned thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, join, external

python code:

```
import threading

def f1():
    #long looping

def f2():
    #another long looping  

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f2)

t1.start()
t2.start()   

#t2.join(t1) <---???
```

Is that possible in main thread to call something like `t2.join(t1)`?
Understanding that I can call `t2.join()` from `f1()`, but I am seeking an way calling from external(not in t1 and t2).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant specify a thread in the join method.

If you want to wait for both t1 and t2 to complete before continuing execution in the main thread, join both threads:

```
import threading
import time

def f1():
    #long looping

def f2():
    #another long looping  

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f2)

t1.start()
t2.start()   

t1.join()
t2.join()

print("Continuing with main thread...")
```

Comment: thank you, the sample code is not I wanted, since all tx.join() are join to main(), I want make t2 to join to t1 some how by calling from main directly.